# Angular material table, how to format output

Tags: html, angular, tags

I am working on Angular module, and I am fetching data from web api.
I am displaying web api response in a mat table. 
I have a list of strings that I want to display with line break.
To do that I am formatting the response and adding `<span> and <br>`  tags. 
But the output is displaying the `<span> and <br>` tags also. 
[image]
Here is my code.

```
   const data:any=[];

        this.receiveService.get(this._parentLocID).subscribe(
            res => {
                res.forEach( g1=>{
                    let nstatus=[];
                    let newstatus=g1.status;

                      newstatus.forEach(
                        res1=>{

                            nstatus.push('<span>'+res1+'</span>'+'<br>');
                        }
                    );
                 g1.status=nstatus;
                 data.push(g1);       
            });

        const resultData: any = data;
        this.dataSource.data = resultData;
```

My objective is simple, I want the values 'completed','In progress' and 'Queued' in separate lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it this way. It was much simpler than I thought.
I had to put *ngIf within mat-cell. And for each item in the array,I put an "br" tag at the end of each item.

```
           <mat-cell  *matCellDef="let element">
                <p class="font-weight-600 text-center" *ngIf="columns.key=='Status'">
                  <span *ngFor="let item of element[columns.value]">
                    {{ item }}
                    <br>
                    </span>
                </p>
                <p class="font-weight-600 text-center" *ngIf="columns.key!='Status'">
                  {{element[columns.value]}}
                 </p>
            </mat-cell>
```

also, I removed this part from .ts file.

```
res.forEach( g1=>{
                let nstatus=[];
                let newstatus=g1.status;

                  newstatus.forEach(
                    res1=>{

                        nstatus.push('<span>'+res1+'</span>'+'<br>');
                    }
                );
             g1.status=nstatus;
             data.push(g1);       
        });
```

so the .ts is

```
 this.receiveService.get(this._parentLocID).subscribe(
        res => { 
                const resultData: any = res;
                this.dataSource.data = resultData;
        }
```

that solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In order to bind HTML content you should use [innerHTML] property, you can find more details in this article

https://www.google.com/amp/s/blog.fullstacktraining.com/binding-html-with-angular/amp/

I fell in your scenario instead of building HTML in typescript you can push only string values and use ngFor in HTML and bind it to {{content}} something like that will be a better option.

Comment: Hi Suresh. 
I had tried to follow your suggestion. I have created pipe, just as described in the link provided. and my html page look like:

     <ng-container *ngFor="let columns of recordsColumns" [
            
                    <p class="font-weight-600 text-center">
                      {{element[columns.value]| sanitizeHtml}}
                    </p>
                  </mat-cell>
                  
                </ng-container>

But the output is completly destroyed,

Comment: Hi, can you provide a stackblitz example?

Comment: Hi Suresh, I didnt understnad what stackblitz means

Comment: Hi, you can recreate your issue in https://stackblitz.com/ and can share it with others so that they look into your code and provide you a fix

Comment: Hi Suresh, I have solved it myself. The solution is below.